# Getting more than 8 colors in a terminal emulator inside Emacs

Tags: colors, ansi-term, multi-term

My understanding is that `ansi-term` only supports 8 colors (a good discussion of this in reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/44iwx0/emacs_internal_terminal_emulator_with_more_than_8/?)).

Meanwhile, an increasing number of terminal emulators (e.g. `tmux` or `iTerm2` in OS X) support `True color` (24 bit, i.e. **16 million** colors). A good list can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728).

- If the 8-color cap is specific to `ansi-term`, are there any other packages for terminal emulation that are trying to address this limitation?
- Are there any plans to bring `True color` support to a terminal emulator in Emacs?

And maybe to confirm:

- Is there any way to effectively have more than 8 colors in  `ansi-term` buffers?
- Is tweaking `ansi-color-names-vector` still the recommended way of setting `ansi-term` colors in Emacs `25`?

---

### How to test if an emulator supports "**True color**":

Here is a snippet from the link above that would test if the emulator supports True colors:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    s="/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\"; s=s s s s s s s s;
    for (colnum = 0; colnum<77; colnum++) {
        r = 255-(colnum*255/76);
        g = (colnum*510/76);
        b = (colnum*255/76);
        if (g>255) g = 510-g;
        printf "\033[48;2;%d;%d;%dm", r,g,b;
        printf "\033[38;2;%d;%d;%dm", 255-r,255-g,255-b;
        printf "%s\033[0m", substr(s,colnum+1,1);
    }
    printf "\n";
}'
```

If it is supported, the bottom line would display a nice gradient like the one shown below:

[image]

---

From what I read, [NeoVim (a VIM editor) added support for it](https://twitter.com/_Felipe/status/582762742345560065) in 2015, and there was [a request](http://emacs.1067599.n5.nabble.com/bug-20243-True-color-terminal-support-tc354040.html) made to Emacs bugs to add it.

Comment: As of Emacs 26, I cannot see `ansi-color-names-vector` as a variable I can customize. Besides that, I run `multi-term` and with zsh as shell. Your script does not produce a positive output :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that ansi-term only supports 8 colors, but, using xterm-color.el instead of ansi-color.el, you get 256 colors.

"ANSI & xterm-256 color text property translator for Emacs"

https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color

Comment: How exactly would I use this with `ansi-term` in Emacs?

Comment: It is not the intended usage, but see: https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color/issues/2

Comment: The hack linked to there is now a package you can install and use: https://github.com/dieggsy/eterm-256color -- not true colour, but way more colours.